# Django 1.8 - управление расположением контента

Tags: python, django

Есть набор каких-то блоков на странице, например, статей, нужно управлять их расположением - например, перетаскиванием, или каким-то другим способом. Через админку или прямо на сайте. Как это можно реализовать?

Например, есть модель:

```
class VisualModule(models.Model):
    class Meta: 
        db_table = 'visualmodules'
    visualmodule_img = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    visualmodule_userlogin = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    visualmodule_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Для админки:

```
class VisualModuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['visualmodule_img']

admin.site.register(VisualModule, VisualModuleAdmin)
```

Вывод на страницу:

```
{% block visualmodule %}
<div class="large-8">
{% for visualmodule in visualmodules %}
    {% if visualmodule.visualmodule_enabled == True %}
        <h4>{{ visualmodule.visualmodule_img }}</a></h4>
        <img src="{% static "img/workplace/" %}{{ visualmodule.visualmodule_img }}" />
        <hr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Необходимо управлять порядком вывода элементов на страницу. 
Логичнее, наверное, через админку?

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. Конкретизируйте

Comment: @Lev добавил код примера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы управлять расположением (порядком сортировки), его надо где-то хранить.
Т.е. нужно добавить поле в модель (VisualModule)

```
order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Также, чтобы каждый раз не вспоминать о порядке сортировки при запросах, используем класс Meta - добавляем:

```
ordering = ['order',]
```

Соответственно, через админку можем задавать порядок следования блоков.

Если хотите drag and drop:

- можно добавить через JavaScript, готовый пример [на сайте
  djangosnippets.org](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1053/)
- можно воспользоваться готовым решением - например, [django-admin-sortable](https://github.com/iambrandontaylor/django-admin-sortable)

Аналогично можно и на сайте сделать, но там уже помимо drag-and-drop придется использовать Ajax для обновления поля order у модели.